# Selectpicker multiple overlap other fields bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How researches i made to prevent a multiple selectpicker from overlapping the fields down, i still can't find a solution. I use bootstrap selectpicker 1.12.4.
After many select label1 overlaps label 2.

```
           <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-4">label1</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
            <select class="form-control input-lg  selectpicker" multiple="multiple" data-style="input-lg btn-default"  data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true">
            <?php 

            foreach($especialidades as $row)
            { 
            echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->title.'</option>';
            }
            ?>
            </select>
            </div>
            </div>      

            <div class="form-group" >
            <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="form_email">label 2</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input  type="text"  class="form-control"  >
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough. Can you show an example to your code? Or a visual representation of what's happening against what you want to happen?

Comment: after i select many values, select field extend down side and hide the second field (label 2)

Comment: Okay, have you inspected the field and done any CSS changes to stop it? Sounds like the select element is floated.

Comment: How can i push down the second field as long as select field is extending down ?

Comment: Like I've just said, inspect it, and you'll be able to see your CSS styling, and then you can change it to get the stylign you need. At the moment, no one can visualise anything.

Comment: I don't know yet how to show a visual representation. It's like the multiple selectpicker field contains 6 elements after selecting then it gets extented down and hide the other field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157078/discussion-between-diasline-and-lee).

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in a manner where `selectpicker` is the culprit (See: https://codepen.io/rkieru/pen/YrBgKp ).  The issue I keep running into is that your column count forces the input after `label 2` to a new line.  Adjusting the column sizes corrects that issue entirely.